# Using sparse matrix in random forest

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, random-forest

For efficient memory utilization, I have  used “matrix" package in R to create sparse matrix using code:

```
library(randomForest)
library(Matrix)
documentTermMatrixFrame <- Matrix(documentTermMatrixFrame, sparse = TRUE)
trainSet <- documentTermMatrixFrame[1:750,]
testSet <- documentTermMatrixFrame[751:999,]
fit <- randomForest(trainingColumnNames, data=trainSet)
```

executing random forest got error as below

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
cannot coerce class "structure("dgCMatrix", package = "Matrix")" to a  data.frame
```

```html
<html>
  
  <title> sample of dataset</title>
  <h1>This is a sample of dataset which i am using</h1>
    <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>nitemid</th>
    <th>sUnSpsc</th> 
    <th>productDescription</th>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>7460893</td>
    <td>26121609 </td> 
    <td>Category 6A, Advanced MaTriX, 4-pair, 23 AWG, U/UTP copper cable, Plenum (CMP) Rated, White, 1000ft/305m ""</td>
  </tr>
       <tr>
    <td>7460456</td>
    <td>26121709 </td> 
    <td>Shielded marine MUD-resistant armored copper cable, category 7 S/FTP, low smoke zero halogen (LSZH), 4-pair, conductors are 22 AWG construction with foamed PE insulation, twisted in pairs</td>
  </tr>
       <tr>
    <td>7460856</td>
    <td>26121890 </td> 
    <td>1 PC. = 100 M 2 X 1.5 QMM, 100M SPECIAL DESIGN TO UL CLASS 2 YELLOW TPE OIL-RESISTANT AS-INTERFACE SHAPED CABLE</td>
  </tr>
</html>
```

Now I need to know how to use that sparse matrix  as input to randomforest() function in randomForest package.. 
Could anyone please help me out??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a bit more details to your question? What packages are you using? Can you make it reproducible? Share a small portion of your data, or ideally, simulate it, which reproduces the error.

Comment: where is your response variable?

Comment: `randomForest` does not work with sparse matrices.